# What carries over in New Game Plus?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

After completing all of the priority missions in Mass Effect: Andromeda, you're given the opportunity to start a new game using your existing save.

What items, abilities, etc carry over when you do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [twinfinite](http://twinfinite.net/) :

> Once you start your New Game Plus, here’s what will have carried over
> from your last playthrough:
>
> - Your unlocked powers
> - Your skill points
> - Your credits
> - Your levels
> - All your collected research data
> - All items not related to quests
>
> Keep in mind that codex entries, your story choices, mission progress,
> quest-related items, and cryo pod perks will not carry over into the
> New Game Plus run.
>
> From here, you’ll be able to customize your character for this special
> run, in case you want to change your appearance or switch which Ryder
> twin you’ll be playing

Comment: Does it delete the old save? I want to start a new game with all the stuff I have but use a different character, but also keep my first save.